# How can I find and replace in the document in the LyX only without the note

Tags: luatex, lyx, overleaf

Thanks to all
I want to find and replace some words in the document in LyX only without the words in the note. how can I do this. many thanks.

Comment: I don't understand, can you add more details? Can you give a "before" and an "after" (i.e., what you want it to look like after the find/replace)?

Comment: My document contains notes.  I want to replace, say, σ with x in the document.. but I want LyX do not do that in the notes.  In the sense that some mathematical words or symbols that are included in the document are replaced, except for those in the notes.

Comment: For example, I want replace the word "size" with the word "volume" in lyx document. I don't want to happen  this in the notes.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Edit</kbd> → <kbd>Find & Replace (Advanced)...</kbd>
or
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shiht</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

This will ignore yellow notes, whilst  <kbd>Find & Replace (Quick)...</kbd> will search also in that notes.

Comment: I tried this way, but it didn't work.

Comment: @user35528 Pay attention to the options  of the Advanced Find & Replace window. With   no options activated in the two tabs, the notes are omitted in my LyX, but at  least check "Search backwards" will produce that a "Replace All"  with touch also the yellow notes.